# i cannot understand part of a proof of ${f_n}$ < $\phi^{n-1}$ , n$\ge$2

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

proof(PMI):

let p(n) denote the given statement

basis step.

when n=2, $f_2$ = 1 < (1+ $\sqrt {5}$)/2 = $\phi$ , so p(2) is true

induction step

assume p(2), p(3), ..., p(k) are true, that is $f_i$ < $\phi^{i-1}$ , 2 $\le$ i $\le$ k

then $\phi^{k} $ = $\phi^{k-1} $ + $\phi^{k-2} $ > $f_k$ + $f_{k-1}$ = $f_{k+1}$

thus, p(k) implies p(k+1), so the result holds for every n $\ge$ 2

what i dont underestand:

how is this possible?
$\phi^{k} $ = $\phi^{k-1} $ + $\phi^{k-2} $ > $f_k$ + $f_{k-1}$ = $f_{k+1}$

a new exponent rule or what?

Comment: Note that $\phi$ is a root of the equation $x^2 - x- 1 = 0$. So for any $k \geq 0$, $\phi^{k} - \phi^{k-1} - \phi^{k-2} = \phi^{k-2} (\phi^2 - \phi - 1) = 0$. Hence, $\phi^{k} = \phi^{k-1} + \phi^{k-2}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Since
$
\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}
$
we obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{1-\phi}&=1-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\,\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{1+\sqrt{5}}\\&=-\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}
\,\,\color{blue}{=-\frac{1}{\phi}}
\end{align*}

It follows
\begin{align*}
\phi^k=\phi^{k-1}\phi=\phi^{k-1}\left(1-\left(1-\phi\right)\right)=\cdots
\end{align*}